# increase the maximum brightness for a laptop replacement screen

Tags: lcd, display, brightness

I would like to increment the maximum brightness for a laptop replacement screen such as this one

[image: generic front lcd screen replacement part]
[image: generic back lcd screen replacement part]

How difficult that could be? I haven't bought the screen yet so any hint about the type / model and the interface for the controller is welcome.
This is not going to be powered via a battery (so power consumption is not a problem), I am trying to build something that will be visible outdoors, from a normal computer reading distance.

Comment: To be readable outdoors, what you would want is to avoid glares from other light sources, especially the sun. Increasing brightness may not help. What is the screen technology? LED ? LCD ? other ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can only use the maximum brightness allowed by the manufacturer without taking it apart. Most of the laptop screens are LCD. For these, you might not be able to find a backlight brighter than normal. It is a meticulous task speaking from my experience.
I would rather suggest that you find an LED display. It has a lot more brightness and contrasts making it more readable outdoors. controllers and driver boards are available on eBay. First, make sure the driver board is available for that particular screen then choose the screen. Also, add a matt filter to avoid screen glare.

Comment: Do you know a quick way to check for the max brightness before buying?

Comment: You can google the spec sheet for that model number. I recently bought LP156WF6 and a quick google search gave me the brightness of 300 cd/m²

Answer (score 1):

These LCD panels come with built-in LED strips. Some of them come with even the backlight driver (so the laptop MoBo generates PWM/brightness signals). Since the maximum brightness is determined by the LEDs, it's not that easy to directly increase the max brightness. You may;

- either replace the internal LED strips manually (same wiring and packaging required)
- or find another panel with higher brightness.

I prefer 2nd option. Your panel's max brightness should be something like 200-250 cd/m² (Candelas per sq-m, aka nit) which is a common value. Nevertheless, you should be able to find a 1920x1200 LVDS panel with a brightness level of 300 or even 400 cd/m².

Comment: thanks, are you sure the measure is mcd? majority of these panels are advertised as 250cd/m2 capable... am I wrong?

Comment: @Edoardo you're right, it's cd/m². Fixed.